# Conceptual question about the dot product

Tags: vectors, inner-products

If $u$ and $v$ are vectors orthogonal to $q$ and $c$ is a scalar, then $q ·(u − cv) = 0$

I created the diagram below to understand what's going on:
[image]
Questions:
When I see c, am I correct in assuming no matter what value it takes - ie no matter how each vector is scaled by c - the dot proudct will always be zero? (I know that even if c=0, the dot product will be zero.

Is drawing a picture the best way to look at this or is there a better way to deal with these sorts of conceptual questions?

Comment: Orthogonality does not depend on the length of the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  No matter the value of $c$, the dot product will be zero.  To prove it, you can distribute the dot product:
$$q\cdot(u-cv) = q\cdot u -q\cdot(cv) = q\cdot u - c(q \cdot v) = 0.$$
Both dot products on the RHS are zero b/c q is orthogonal to both u and v.

Conceptually, the sum $u-cv$ will always be along the same direction as $u,v$.